# Please Help, Cannot call android activity method from other class

Tags: android

I have two classes one is HomeActivity and second is AlarmReciever

In HomeActivity AlarmManager Service created which gives call to AlarmReciver by some specified time

Now i want when AlarmReciver get called then an Dialog should be displayed which is 
defined in HomeActivity

Here is source code of two files and LogCat

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView textView;

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private AlarmManager manager;

    static Dialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);     

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 10000;

        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Antivirus Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

        public void openDialog(){
        dialog = new Dialog(HomeActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.ask_question);
    }
}
```

//And Here is Second Class

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context c;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        HomeActivity home = new HomeActivity();
        home.openDialog();

    }
}
```

// And LogCat

```
10-27 19:51:40.645: D/dalvikvm(27137): Late-enabling CheckJNI
10-27 19:51:41.545: E/DATABASE(27137): SELECT  * FROM register
10-27 19:51:42.075: D/OpenGLRenderer(27137): Enabling debug mode 0
10-27 19:51:52.775: D/AndroidRuntime(27137): Shutting down VM
10-27 19:51:52.785: W/dalvikvm(27137): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41698c08)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137): Process: com.example.malwaredetection, PID: 27137
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.malwaredetection.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2704)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:179)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:166)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:103)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:159)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:136)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at com.example.malwaredetection.HomeActivity.openDialog(HomeActivity.java:87)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at com.example.malwaredetection.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:15)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2687)
10-27 19:51:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(27137):    ... 10 more
10-27 19:52:55.735: D/AndroidRuntime(27939): Shutting down VM
10-27 19:52:55.735: W/dalvikvm(27939): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41698c08)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939): Process: com.example.malwaredetection, PID: 27939
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.malwaredetection.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2704)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:179)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:166)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:103)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:159)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:136)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at com.example.malwaredetection.HomeActivity.openDialog(HomeActivity.java:87)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at com.example.malwaredetection.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:15)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2687)
10-27 19:52:55.745: E/AndroidRuntime(27939):    ... 10 more
10-27 19:53:01.655: D/AndroidRuntime(28095): Shutting down VM
10-27 19:53:01.665: W/dalvikvm(28095): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41698c08)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095): Process: com.example.malwaredetection, PID: 28095
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.malwaredetection.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2704)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:179)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:166)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:103)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:159)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:136)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at com.example.malwaredetection.HomeActivity.openDialog(HomeActivity.java:87)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at com.example.malwaredetection.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:15)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2687)
10-27 19:53:01.735: E/AndroidRuntime(28095):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Well, have you done anything about the errors that were listed in the exception stacktrace?

Comment: yes i tried to pass context to dialog with different techniques and nothing works

Comment: And i don't understand what is token things which mentioned in LogCat

Comment: I also tried different answer from stackoverflow but not any answer suites for my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do: `HomeActivity home = new HomeActivity();` because Activities are meant to be created with intents.

You can do this instead:

**AlarmReceiver:**

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent homeActivityIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    homeActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    homeActivityIntent.putExtra("value_name", "value_data");
    context.startActivity(homeActivityIntent);
}
```

**HomeActivity:**

```
     @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            super.onNewIntent(intent);
            String someData = intent.getStringExtra("value_name");
            //Maybe check value of someData to decide 
            //weather to open the dialog or not
            this.openDialog();
        }
```

Comment: Anyway, this is somewhat limited solution. @MH. has mentioned some better solutions to this problem.

Comment: Please tell me what is the reference to context variable in AlarmReciver

Comment: Hi, you get the context in 'onReceive(Context, arg0, Intent arg1)'. Try using it: 'arg0.startActivity(intent);'

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't do this:

```
HomeActivity home = new HomeActivity()
```

You cannot manually instantiate activity instances. Instead, you should let the system do that for you. If you want to [start a new activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivity), use an `Intent`.

You actual question can be answered in different ways, depending on your requirements and the desired runtime behaviour.

For instance, if you only want to display the dialog while your app is running, you could use one of [many 'event bus' implementations](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/32) available, or just set up your own [(local) broadcast manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) with receiver.

If you also need to show the dialog even if your app is not in the foreground (have a good think about the user experience if you decide to go down this road), you could leverage the [activity launch modes](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes) to start your `HomeActivity`. This approach will enable you to gracefully handle the scenario where a record of the activity already exists on the backstack (as well as where it doesn't).